# How to import dropdown value from table data

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have a java / Spring MVC application that includes forms that interface with tables. On one of the pages, I have designed it so that when a row is clicked on the table, form data is populated using the data that is in that row.

**Javascript code:**

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var idx = table.row(this).index();
    var vName = document.getElementById("userName");
    vName.value = table.cell(idx, 7).data();
```

This works well for the text form fields.  Where I am running into a problem is in the `"userName"` field, since that is a list (`form:select`) field.

I'm not really sure how I would go about the process of having my app be able to locate the list index of a name in the dropdown list based on the text data that it is reading from the table.

**Here is the html for the dropdown field:**

```
<spring:bind path="model.userName">
    <label for="fullName">Select User:</label>
    <form:select cssClass="form-control" path="model.userName" id="userName" name="userName">
        <form:option value=""></form:option>
        <form:options items="${userList}" itemLabel="fullName" itemValue="ID"/>
    </form:select>
</spring:bind>
```

The dropdown list, `${userList}`, is created by building a List in my DAO, along with the following RowMapper method:

```
private static class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        return new Users(rs.getLong("ID"),
        rs.getString("LNAME") + ", " + rs.getString("FNAME"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `value` of a `select` element, in fact you are setting the `option` with this `value` as `selected`, while here you are using the name so you are dealing with the **content** of the `option` and **not it's value**.

So in your example when you have the selected `userName` from your table you just need to loop through the select options and set the appropriate `option` as `selected`.

**This is the code you need:**

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var idx = table.row(this).index();
  var vName = document.getElementById("userName");

  for (i in vName.options) {
    //I test on the innerText here because FF doesn't support it
    var optionText = typeof vName.options[i].innerText !== 'undefined' ? vName.options[i].innerText : vName.options[i].textContent;
    if (optionText === table.cell(idx, 7).data()) {
      vName.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

**This is a brief Snippet Example:**

```js
$('#name').on('change', function() {
  var vName = document.getElementById("userName");
  
  for (i in vName.options) {
    var optionText = typeof vName.options[i].innerText !== 'undefined' ? vName.options[i].innerText : vName.options[i].textContent;
    
    if (optionText === $(this).val()) {
      vName.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter name:
<input type="text" id="name" />
<select name="userName" id="userName">
  <option value="">Muhammad</option>
  <option value="">Alain</option>
  <option value="">John</option>
  <option value="">Ali</option>
  <option value="">Maria</option>
  <option value="">Lee</option>
  <option value="">Alessandro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great, glad it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the best way to get data from a server to the front end is as a JSON string/object then we can easily manipulate that just like you're doing already.

I think you're pretty much there you're just missing one part.

In this below example i'm listing the same users in a table and menu and on click of the table row the selected user in the drop down is defaulted.

For example with this sample table data.

JS:

```
var users = [{
  ID: 0,
  LNAME: "First",
  FNAME: "Senior"
}, {
  ID: 1,
  LNAME: "Second",
  FNAME: "Sir"
}, {
  ID: 2,
  LNAME: "Third",
  FNAME: "Chap"
}, {
  ID: 3,
  LNAME: "Fourth",
  FNAME: "Mr"
}];


mag.module('userName', {
  view: function(state) {

    state.tr = state.option = users.map(function(user) {
      return {
        _selected: user.ID == state.index ? true : null,
        _text: user.FNAME + ' ' + user.LNAME,
        _value: user.ID
      }
    });

    state.$tr = {
      _onclick: function(e, i) {
       state.index = i;
       state.span = users[i].FNAME + users[i].LNAME
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="userName">
  <table>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <label for="fullName">Select User: <span></span></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="userName">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is the full working example: http://jsbin.com/bokiqebezo/1/edit?html,js,output

Hope this helps!